# Android Extend double class

Tags: android, extends

I have my Class Adapter , and I need to have the access of two class ! Then I can put `public class JSONAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Voiture> {` for have access in my class " Voiture " but I need to have the acceesss in my class "Moniteur" too , and I can"t put that :

```
public class JSONAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Voiture>,ArrayAdapter<Moniteur> {
```

I need to view attributes of my class " Voiture " and " Moniteur " ...

Do you have the solution for me please ? Thanks

**EDIT :** Ok thanks you , this is the code of my class VOITURE :

```
public class Voiture {

private int idV = -1; // permet de voir si le parent est enregistré dans la BDD
private String marqueV;
private String dateAchatV;
private String PlaqueImmatriculationV;


public Voiture(String marqueV, String plaqueImmatriculationV) {
    this.marqueV = marqueV;
    PlaqueImmatriculationV = plaqueImmatriculationV;
}

public Voiture(JSONAdapter jsonAdapter) {
    this.marqueV = marqueV;

    this.PlaqueImmatriculationV = PlaqueImmatriculationV;

}



public int getIdV() {
    return idV;
}

public void setIdV(int idV) {
    this.idV = idV;
}

public String getMarqueV() {
    return marqueV;
}

public void setMarqueV(String marqueV) {
    this.marqueV = marqueV;
}

public String getDateAchatV() {
    return dateAchatV;
}

public void setDateAchatV(String dateAchatV) {
    this.dateAchatV = dateAchatV;
}

public String getPlaqueImmatriculationV() {
    return PlaqueImmatriculationV;
}

public void setPlaqueImmatriculationV(String plaqueImmatriculationV) {
    PlaqueImmatriculationV = plaqueImmatriculationV;
}
```

}

This is the code of my class Moniteur :

```
public class Moniteur {

private int idM;
private String nomM;
private String prenomM;
private String adresseM;
private String telephoneM;

public Moniteur(String nomM, String prenomM,String adresseM,String telephoneM) {
    this.nomM = nomM;
    this.prenomM = prenomM;
    this.adresseM = adresseM;
    this.telephoneM = telephoneM;
}



public int getIdM() { return idM; }

public void setIdM(int idM) { this.idM = idM; }

public String getNomM() {
    return nomM;
}

public void setNomM(String nomM) {
    this.nomM = nomM;
}

public String getPrenomM() {
    return prenomM;
}

public void setPrenomM(String prenomM) {
    this.prenomM = prenomM;
}

public String getAdresseM() {
    return adresseM;
}

public void setAdresseM(String adresseM) {
    this.adresseM = adresseM;
}

public String getTelephoneM() {
    return telephoneM;
}

public void setTelephoneM(String telephoneM) {
    this.telephoneM = telephoneM;
}
```

}

Comment: yes, you can't extend more than one class is java. multiple inheritance is not allowed. Use interfaces.

Comment: Maybe if you could [edit] your question to include the code for both `Voiture` and `Moniteur` we could assist you in combining them into an Adapter.

Comment: Please read abstract factory pattern. It has soln for problems like this

Comment: Could you explain your use case? Do you want a list of `Moniteur` or `Voiture`? or both in the same list ...?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of these two classes and how they relate is not clear, but if you want to store both of them in a single container (which is what you are trying to do) you will need to define a common interface between them (or an abstract class). I don't speak French so you will have a easier time creating a good name.

I suggest creating an interface:

```
public interface AbstractItem
{
    //TODO define common functions in this class
}
```

then implement this interface in your classes:

```
public class Voiture implements AbstractItem
{ ... }

public class Moniteur implements AbstractItem
{ ... }
```

Then, you can create an array adapter that will hold both of these items:

```
public class JSONAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AbstractItem> 
{ ... }
```

Comment: I would use an abstract class instead of an interface. For example, the `id` value is obviously shared. Interfaces don't have instance variables.

Comment: I had that exact thought just before your comment and had updated the answer to include "or an abstract class". Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay i understand but ... just one things , where i create the interface AbstractItem ? I need to create a new class ?

Comment: @krowry Yes you should create a new file for the `interface` or `abstract class`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, "Voiture" means "car" and "Moniteur" means "instructor" or "teacher".

So, it sounds like you are implementing a type of "driving school" where there are teachers with cars that they use/drive.

If that is the case, you really only need an `ArrayAdapter<Monituer>` and you could implement your `Moniteur` class like so.

```
public class Moniteur {
    private List<Voiture> voitures;

    public Monituer() {
        voitures = new ArrayList<Voiture>();
    }

    public void ajouterVoiture(Voiture v) {
        voitures.add(v);
    }

    public List<Voiture> obtientVoitures() {
       return voitures;
    }

}
```

Or maybe I don't understand what is trying to be displayed in the adapters. In that case, feel free to comment below.

Comment: Ok i try this . Thanks you !